# Exclude root directory from htaccess redirection

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my .htaccess but I would also like to exlude the root directory ('mysite.com' slash nothing) from the rule.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(wp-admin|index.php)
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\D]+)$ /index.php?username=$1  [L]`

Any thoughts? :)

Answer (score 0):

To exclude the root dir, put this condition above your rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$
```

Comment: Thank you. If I put that line above the others it doesn't work. If I substitute it for the first one it says 'The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.' What might it be?

Comment: Sorry I didnt notice it but your orignal rule already excludes the root dir. What exactly Is your problem.?

Comment: I want to exclude "slash nothing". All other requests to be redirected to index.php

Comment: What do you mean "slash nothing"? The rule you posted does not redirect example.com/ to index.php

Comment: It actually is redirecting example.com/ to index.php (tried it). Why do you say it is? It's just excluding index.php to avoid a loop. I'm new to this.

Comment: index.php is your root directory handler. The rule does not redirect exampl.com/ to /index.php it is Directory module that performs this redirection. Do you want to change the directory index file ?

Comment: Ah, that's what was happening. I used a different file for the redirection. Thank you! If you write that as an answer I'll mark it